How do I start a GUI app on Mac with arguments?
I want to create a desktop icon in VSCode that will open a text file in my journal that I use on a daily basis. All I need to do is run the following command, code --new-window "diary.txt"
But I cannot open the terminal every time I write a diary. I want the above command to be executed by simply double clicking on the icon I have placed on my desktop.
I want to create a diary.command file, grant execute permission to the I have described the above command. The terminal window remains open at the same time as VSCode.
I cannot change the settings of the terminal itself. In Windows, this can be easily accomplished by creating a shortcut to the exe file and opening the properties screen.
I mentioned “diary” as an example. In fact, it is essential to execute any command line in hidden mode. So I am not looking for answers such as using VSCode extensions.
Security-wise, there should be no problem since I will be triggering the double-click on the icon myself. I am not talking about automatically executing the command in hidden.

I asked on Stack Overflow and was guided to this location as appropriate and resubmitted.

Look at Automater.app

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Create a shortcut.sh (or just leave out the extension to make it a "UNIX executable") file with content:
#!/bin/sh
code --new-window “diary.txt”

Then in terminal run chmod +x shortcut.sh
Put it on your desktop/dock, double click it, mission accomplished.
If this doesn't work, you can also write a simple C program that execve() "code".
As a less general approach, you can use vscode:// URL scheme as documented here.

Is there any way to just double click on the desktop icon like a normal app and have it run without opening a terminal other than the app?

If I remember correctly, my method would open app without terminal, as long as it is a UNIX executable rather than a shell script. I don't have a mac near me, but you can try it out.
